# Meteor: onConnection, check if user is logged in

Tags: javascript, meteor, server, meteor-accounts

I'm using the onConnection hook and some template helpers to do some stuff with statistics. But now, I want't to exclude these operations when I'm a registered user. 
The Problem, I can't use Meteor.user() in the onConnection hook, so how can i check if a user is logged in ?

Concerning code, there is not much to show

```
Meteor.onConnection(function(conn) {
 if(Meteor.user()) {
  console.log("you are logged in")
 } else {
  console.log("u are not logged in")
 }
});
```

It's not the true example but it shows simple what i want to do 
The Error

```
err [Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.]
```

I understand that i can just use Meteor.user() in methods, but how can i find out in the onConnection if a user is logged in ?

Comment: show the code for what you've tried, please.

Comment: @zim Added an example

Comment: did you try using this.userId, as shown in the error message?

Comment: i did but this is no publish message, therefore, not working The point is that I'm using it nether in a publish function or a method...

Comment: sorry, don't know. i read the docs and it doesn't give any indication of associating that connection with a user.

Comment: Did the same but still thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For statistics purposes I'd recommend to use publications. They have more sophisticated api which allows you to have more control over your connection.

```
Meteor.publish('users.trackPresence', function() {
  // Both this.userId && this.connection are available to be called from here

  this.onStop(function(){
    // user went offline
  });

  this.ready();
});
```

and on the client you can check if user is present and not even subscribe if this is the case:

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
  if (!Meteor.userId())
    Meteor.subscribe('users.trackPresence');
});
```

Meteor automatically handles unsubscribe/resubscribe when you subscribe from within a Tracker.autorun

read more about pubsub api here
https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html

Answer (score 0):

Obviously as you stated, the Meteor docs do not provide any insight for how to achieve this.  I spent a decent amount of time going thru the `accounts-base` source and don't see any way to do what you are asking natively.

With that said, if you could update the `Users` collection each time they login and save their current IP address, then you could use this as a way to see if the current connection is logged in.  Here is an example.

```
Meteor.onConnection((connection) => {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne({
    'user.profile.currentIp': connection.clientAddress
  });

  if (user) {
    console.log("you are logged in")
  } else {
    console.log("u are not logged in")
  }
});
```

Be sure to add login and logout hooks to set and remove the user's current IP.  I have not tested this approach, but in theory it should work.

Comment: Is it possible to use onConnection in the client side?

Comment: Nope, its on the server only

Comment: @Ruben There is a `Meteor.connection` object that you can access on the client...perhaps that has a similar method inside it?  I have used it before to print to the console all the DDP incoming/outgoing messages.